# Why Does The Background Image Not Show in Orthographic View?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, image, world, orthographic

I have added a background image to the world settings. However, it has disappeared from my 3D view and only shows when I view the scene from the camera. Does anyone know if there is something I can do to make it reappear?

[image: camera view shows background]

[image: background not showing in 3D view]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you are in ortho view, so you will only see one pixel of the background image at a time (if you rotate the 3D view around, the background color should change).

Switch to perspective (<kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>), and it should appear normally.

Comment: Thank you, this was driving me nuts since there are so many different ways to deactivate the environment texture/world background, I didn't look for less obvious settings like ortho mode.