# Fake reflections in Cycles, redux

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

In the [Fake reflections in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2030/fake-reflections-in-cycles) question, there is an example of a simple shader set up. I tried it, the image is displayed in my Preview (Blender 2.73a). The rendered object shows reflection but no image. Why is my image not showing in the new version of Blender?

Jonathan Williamson has an example of how to do this on cgcookie (http://cgcookie.com/archive/tip-faking-reflections/), but it's dated 2010 so the Blender version is different - using Blender Render, not Cycles.

Comment: Is it possible you could add some screenshots of the setup and result?

Comment: Simple as I can make it. I'm a novice so this could be a noob mistake, or simply a misunderstanding. Link demo here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3504807/FakeReflectionFolder.zip

Comment: It seems to be working for me..

Comment: Here: http://www.pasteall.org/pic/85428. I noticed you were in orthographic view, which would prevent you from seeing more than a single point on the texture at once (see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14219/599). Try switching to perspective view (Numpad 5) and see if that helps.

Comment: Due to the way reflection coordinates work scaling is a bit non-trivial. You might be better off using a 2D plane with the logo texture, positioned so that the mirror reflects it

Answer (score 4):

To reply here as well just in case others are looking for the same thing, you can achieve the same fake reflection effect with the following node setup:
[image]