# Confused as to how World Background HDR works

Tags: interface

I am using 2.74RC but get the same results with 2.73

If I add an Environmental Texture HDR it shows in the World Preview. It also shows in the final render BUT it doesn't show in a SHIFT-Z render although it appears to be "there" because the colours vary if I rotate the scene. Same thing for "Solid" mode if I check "World Background" under the Display tab.

In another model I have the World Background DOES show in "Solid" mode and in a final render but again not in SHIFT-Z (Render) mode.

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: Is it possible you are in ortho view? See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14219/599

Comment: Are you in perspective or orthographic view?

Comment: is this a confirmed duplicate @gandalf3 ?

Comment: @Chebhou Not sure.. I don't see why it would be working in solid view in ortho view,  which makes me think maybe there is something else going on. Need more info

Comment: I am in Ortho. That was what I was "missing". Embarrassing.

Comment: It is a mystery then, that I have a model wherein the World Background shows up in "Solid" mode while in Ortho. Essentially this is what threw me off.

Comment: Unlike objects, HDRI background cannot be displayed properly in orthographic view. The image is projected 360  degrees around the center of the view point. Once you change to orthographic view, the background looks like it is a solid color because the view is directed to a single point on HDRI image, that is perpendicular to the viewing angle.