# Background environment texture not rendered in viewport or final render

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

How do i make this visible?.

Every tutorial I see, it is automatic. But my scene is not mine, aparently they made it invisible, but I want to see how it is positioned and I need it to be displayed in the viewport with rendered option on.

Comment: Please provide more details to your question and attach the blend file if you can.

Comment: What is displayed instead of the background? Do you have *transparent film* enabled? Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14219/599

Comment: I can't post the file here, it's private content. I just render, and the environment texture set is not displayed when i render with Cycles. But the effects of it over the specular are visible. I just want to position the environment. In the examples I've seen in tutorials, it is available and can be seen

Comment: gandalf3, nothing is displayed. It's black. What is a transparent film?

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Render Properties* tab under *Film* and deselect *Transparency*, only works for Cycles.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to turn on *Use Nodes* just under your image

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Your environment is disabled.

Check your scene settings, "use environment".

Comment: This is a 3y old question! But anyway, try to detail more what could solve this... I could not get what you meant.